# How do I delete rows which have only one entry in multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have the following type of muti-index dataframe:

```
import random
col3=[0,0,0,0,2,4,6,0,0,0,100,200,300,400]
col4=[0,0,0,0,4,6,8,0,0,0,200,900,400, 500]

d = {'Unit': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6], 
 'Year': [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017], 'col3' : col3, 'col4' : col4 }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
new_df = df.groupby(['Unit', 'Year']).sum()

           col3  col4     
Unit Year                      
1    2014     0     0      
     2015     0     0       
     2016     0     0      
     2017     0     0      
2    2015     2     4       
     2016     4     6  
     2017     6     8  
3    2017     0     0    
4    2014     0     0      
5    2015     0     0      
6    2014   100   200       
     2015   200   900  
     2016   300   400  
     2017   400   500
```

In reality it is larger ofcourse, but this does the job. In this dataframe I want to remove all Units, which have only one year entry. So I want to have this:

```
           col3  col4     
Unit Year                      
1    2014     0     0      
     2015     0     0       
     2016     0     0      
     2017     0     0      
2    2015     2     4       
     2016     4     6  
     2017     6     8         
6    2014   100   200       
     2015   200   900  
     2016   300   400  
     2017   400   500
```

Thank you in advance for help,

Jen

Comment: Thanx you, that is a mistake indeed. Should also be removed, i edit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with any column and test counts with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), compare for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = new_df[new_df.groupby(level=0)['col3'].transform('size').ne(1)]
```

Or get values of index by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and filter by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
df = new_df[new_df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)]
```

---

```
print (df)
           col3  col4
Unit Year            
1    2014     0     0
     2015     0     0
     2016     0     0
     2017     0     0
2    2015     2     4
     2016     4     6
     2017     6     8
6    2014   100   200
     2015   200   900
     2016   300   400
     2017   400   500
```